# Is space elevator a reasonable idea?

Tags: space-elevator, japan

I read today that [Japan is trying to build space elevator by 2050](https://gizmodo.com/5887210/japan-will-have-a-space-elevator-by-2050). To me, it sounds like making a super skyscraper. There are so many challenges building skyscraper that exist today. It is an ecosystem in itself and require lots of maintenance. How feasible is the idea of space elevator, considering various parameters i.e. terrorist attack, maintenance, etc.?

Comment: ...and even 2050 is overly optimistic. It's a date when we might possess all necessary technology to build it - add another 50 years to give it a chance to become economically viable, said technology cheap and ubiquitous enough.

Answer (score 2):

There is a lot of information already that has no need to be duplicated here, hence the down votes
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Space_elevator
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Space_elevator_safety
Short answer: until recently the the concept was provably impossible on material strength grounds, this is no longer the case but that does not automatically make the concept viable, sensible or safe.

Comment: A thing worth mentioning IMO, that is regularly omitted when talking about space elevators and material strength is active support, so I would add provably impossible on material strength grounds, without using active support, on Earth. Also, there are different designs and variations like skyhooks e.g.